# How to filter content in CK Editor 5

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am new in javascript and CK Editor,
After adding some HTML content editor automatically remove classes from content

Normal HTML Content :
`<dic class="heading">HEAD</div>`

CK Editor Content :
`<dic>HEAD</div>`

[FAQ](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/faq.html#why-does-the-editor-filter-out-my-content-styles-classes-elements-where-is-configallowedcontent-true)

i can't understand FAQ ans so i attached link

Comment: CK editor strips the HTML tags as you realised. 
If you want to include HTML tags in the content, you have to define them in the CK Editor Data Model format. The way to do this is converting your HTML code to View format by using `editor.data.processor.toView` method and then convert this to Model format and then manually insert it to the editor `editor.model.insertContent( modelFragment );`

Comment: thanks @trkaplan. can you elaborate with sample code. i don't know javascript 
    ```.then( editor => {
    window.editor = editor;
    editor.plugins.get( 'CommentsOnly' ).isEnabled = true
} )```